# Jhipster JPA - delete Entity after expired

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jhipster

I have a JPA entity table with a ZonedDateTime field (generated using Jhipster JDL studio).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "randomTable")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class RandomTable implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "data", nullable = false)
    private ZonedDateTime data;

}
```

I want to make it so that when the current date/time has gone past the date described in my ZonedDateTime field, the entity in my database gets deleted. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to go about doing that is to create a task bean that runs every few minutes and checks all the entities to see if they are expired, then deletes the expired ones. Look into the `@Scheduled` annotation.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks

https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Comment: These annotation make programming way to easy :). Thanks for the help !